Making a map in highcharts using velocity
I am trying to make a map in velocity for my chart that is rendered through the highcharts API. I have many following methods, and none seem to work. My first example is what I want to see. The rest are just random tests.
#set($queryArray = 
    {
        "name" : "Approved", 
        "query" : "test"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Proposed", 
        "query" : "test"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Draft", 
        "query" : "test"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Blank", 
        "query" : "test"
    }
)

The error for the above 'map' is as such: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<',
Leading me here:
var options = <span class="polarion-rp-widget-warning" style="display:block;"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i>There was an exception (see server log for details) Encountered "\n" at line 12, column 20.
Was expecting one of:
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    <NUMBER_LITERAL> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "{" ...
    "!" ...
    </span>;

Now, for my next attempt at a map:
#set($queries)
#set($queries.Map = {"banana" : "good", "roast beef" : "bad"})

The error for the above 'map' is as such: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<',
Leading me here:
var options = <span class="polarion-rp-widget-warning" style="display:block;"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i>There was an exception (see server log for details) Encountered ")\n" at line 12, column 14.
Was expecting one of:
    <WHITESPACE> ...
    "=" ...
    <DOT> ...
    </span>;

My last map attempt:
#set($queryMap = $objectFactory.newMap)
$queryMap.put("Dog")

The error for the above 'map' is as such: Uncaught ReferenceError: $queryMap is not defined,
Leading me here:
$queryMap.put("Dog")

I am quite lost, as these are the only methods for a map in velocity that I saw posted on the internet. Documentation was not very helpful but maybe I missed something. Help would be most appreciated.

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with velocity. But these errors looks like you're providing the data in a wrong format. Please check the Highcharts docs to see what the data format should be: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data Probably your data should look like that:         List<Map<String, Object>> seriesData = Arrays.asList(
Map.of("x", 0, "y", 1),
Map.of("x", 1, "y", 3));

The error I am receiving has to do with how the map is being shown in velocity, not highcharts.

Oh, then I'm afraid we need to wait for a velocity expert
